# problem in the deployment for windows application with using express edition 2010 with database?

Tags: c#, sql, deployment

I made an  windows application using c# express edition 2010 and i use the SQL database as mdf file inside my soultion and the connection string mad automaticaly in the app.config as the following:

```
 <add name="MainForm.Properties.Settings.FamilyHistoryConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FamilyHistory.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

then when i am trying to publish the project using "publish" from the project properties then the setup.exe and other files appear
when i am trying to install it in my machine again ti test it this Error appears:

```
 See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\MyComputerName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\MDXORHTD.5GQ\JR6MCHOZ.O0K\fami..tion_6534de728ebbf078_0001.0000_070d979a18d3a32b\Relative.xml'.
File name: 'C:\Users\MyComputerName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\MDXORHTD.5GQ\JR6MCHOZ.O0K\fami..tion_6534de728ebbf078_0001.0000_070d979a18d3a32b\Relative.xml'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at Family_History.Form1.FillCombo(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb, String FileName)
   at Family_History.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Family_History
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/MyComputerName/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/MDXORHTD.5GQ/JR6MCHOZ.O0K/fami..tion_6534de728ebbf078_0001.0000_070d979a18d3a32b/Family_History.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I don't know how to solve it and i don't know how to change the connection string in the customer machine
if you need more information to clarify the problem let me know...
i need help quickly please :)

Comment: Can you edit your question as I see it messing up the browser with those big fonts... ( using chrome )

Comment: i think now is better :)

Answer (score 1):

The Error seems to be about a `Relative.xml` file, not the database....

Do you deploy this file?  (Include it in content files when publishing).

Comment: this file is inside the solution of the project in the bin  "the folder of the project" so its deployed with project

Comment: Better check and doublecheck. The error contains the Path, maybe start an explorer "As Admin" to find it.

Comment: i added the Relative.xml again and the same problem appears so i will remove it and check again

Comment: yesss i did itThank you :) i coped all XML files in the path but now how to change the connection string in customer machine and what i need to download in the customer machine to make the program work because all of this tests still in my machine

Comment: @user## Even with a local .MDF file, you will still need to install SqlExpress...  Using SqlCe could be easier for ClickOnce

Comment: For SqlCe, use Add Local Database file (*.sdf)

Comment: look this my first time to deploy a project with 2010 so could you please tell me more about how to change the connection string in the user machine if i am using mdf file inside my solution :) ..Thanks in advance

Comment: @special, changing the conn string won't help if you don't run Sql Express. For the settings, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/