# |DataDirectory| in Project properties > Settings

Tags: c#

The connection string setting is below:

> Name:
>   dbPersonConnectionString
>
> Type: 
>   Connection string
>   Scope: 
>   Application
>
> Value:
>   Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbPerson.sdf

When I install & run the application, it looks for DB in C:\MyApp\Data\ folder. It should be C:\MyApp without additional \Data folder.

Should I simply create Data folder in my project and move DB files under that folder or I simply adjust |DataDirectory| -and how-?

EDIT:

```
        string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",path);
```

Comment: Are you deploying as ClickOnce?

Comment: Yes, it's a ClickOnce project.

Comment: That explains the changed default. Maybe just go with the flow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been asked before. This [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/) gives a good overview.

It should indeed default to your binaries folder, you can change it with `AppDomain.SetData()` . If you change it, better do it early.

Comment: An SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented/1409378#1409378

Answer (score 5):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

This should work always because Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() may return other directory than the executable one

Comment: where this code should be placed in my winform app?

Answer (score 1):

This one solved my problem

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```