# Need to change connection string every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datasource

I build a register but every time I move pc, I need to change the string connection.

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/3CN3TmdB

How can I not have to change the data source every time I'm changing computer?
If anyone could help me, that would be great!
Thanks for any help.

This is my connection string:

`string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Gal\Desktop\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\App_Data\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";`

Comment: Why would you need to change the connection string on every computer?

Comment: You can investigate if `|DataDirectory|` can help you. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented)

Comment: Beacuse of this: C:\Users\Gal\Desktop\WebApplication2\WebApplication2,
in every pc, its diffrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `|DataDirectory|` placeholder:

```
string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

.NET will replace the value of `|DataDirectory|` at runtime with the path to your `App_Data` folder.

Comment: You should use `|DataDirectory|` as that is standard way of dynamically pointing to your `App_Data` folder in .NET connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

you can put connection string in a seperate file
you can use udl file
steps for use udl:
1-create text file
2-change the extension of text file to .udl
3-open udl file and choose provider then connection parameters
4-save and close file

in c# code you can refer to this file
string connection = @"File Name=myudlFileName.udl";