# set "Application.StartupPath" in may app.config connectionstring

Tags: c#

**in App.Config file :**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB_PhonebookEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB_Phonebook;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**in MyModel.Designer.cs file :**

```
namespace SimplePhoneBook
{
    public partial class DB_PhonebookEntities : ObjectContext
    {            
        public DB_PhonebookEntities() : base("name=DB_PhonebookEntities", "DB_PhonebookEntities")
        {            
            ....
        }

        public DB_PhonebookEntities(string connectionString): base(connectionString, "DB_PhonebookEntities") 
        {
            ....
        }

        public DB_PhonebookEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "DB_PhonebookEntities")
        {
            ....
        }

        ....        
    }
```

How can I set `Application.StartupPath` into my ConnectionString?

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Just leave it as is, instead, at runtime use the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) in your code to fix the parts that are not valid.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "set "Application.StartupPath" into my ConnectionString", what part of the value returned by `Application.StartupPath` is usefull when setting a connection string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADO.NET  |DataDirectory| where is this documented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented)

Comment: You would only need a specific path if your connection string was trying to attach a file but your connection string connects to a server. Even then, you can configure the `DataDirectory` in code

Comment: For the sqlite database,  i have solved this problem, if you have not fixed yet let me know

Answer (score 0):

I want create "Model" from my database thais on the applicatin path(...\debug\bin\mydatabase.mdf)

and using entities in my model!

Answer (score 0):

Append this to your connection string. This will point to WebApplication1\App_Data. So your mdf file should be in App_Data folder

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20141203171438.mdf
```

Comment: "windows application", no Web application

Comment: "System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath" will give you path. Also mark mdf file atttribute "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always"