# Change database file path to its installation path

Tags: c#, database

I am using MDF file for database in windows form for that purpose I have to write the full path in the connection string i.e.

```
Data Source=`(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\adeel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WPFwithSampleDB\WPFwithSampleDB\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

I want to change this path of `AttachDbFilename` as user install my program in their machine, I changed this path to

```
(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

But it does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADO.NET  |DataDirectory| where is this documented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented)

Comment: @user2946329 thanks its work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `|DataDirectory|`. It eliminates the need to hard-code the full path and also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy an application. Like this:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;
```

Have a look at this: [`Working with local databases`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx).