# Database connection not working in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, dbcontext

I just create a new ASP MVC sample. The code was generate with scaffolding. Then I run the application and it runs smooth. But when I click "Register" link in top nav bar and tries to register it does not work.

**My Connection String:**

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProductExa‌​mple-20151218101004.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProductExample-20151218101004;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a problem in your connection string.

Comment: Hello Emmad Zahid, It is saying that the Connection String is not proper. Please check your connection with sql server.

Comment: I am new to ASP MVC.
But this is my connection string

<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProductExample-20151218101004.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProductExample-20151218101004;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

I havent changed it.

Comment: Please check in your AppData folder, Is there any file named aspnet-ProductExa‌​mple-20151218101004.mdf. If not you need to add one.

Comment: No there is no database file. I have refreshed the view too.

Comment: See you have got your culprit. No database file then such kind of exception surely would raise. Kindly add one :)

Comment: I knew that there is no database file, but why it not creating database? All I want to know is what is the issue with connection string? I havent changed the string. It just comes with scaffolding.

Comment: Guys its working now. I just changed the connection string to <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/> and its working. I dont know why, can some one explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that your connection with sql server is not established.

Please check your connection string.

Here i am showing mine. Please check it once. It may help you.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DemoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Report.DemoEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.Report.DemoEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.Report.DemoEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.1.2\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DEMODB;user id=abc;password=abc;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Check all following parameters are correct or not.

> data source=192.168.1.2\SQLEXPRESS;
>
> initial catalog=DEMODB;
>
> user id=abc;
>
> password=abc;

According to your sql server configuration you need to correct your connection string.

I needed to write IP\InstaceName may be in your you only need to write IP or only instace name. Please check it once.

Comment: I changed my string to <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> and its working now.Can some one explain me why its working?

Comment: See here you corrected your sql instance name and DB path. you can check following link to know about |DataDirectory|. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented

Answer (score -1):

check sql server express is install or not on your machine if not then use local sql server that is install on your machine and change connection string
    data source=.;
    initial catalog=DEMODB;
    user id=abc;
    password=123;