# Get an insert query to run after a . click event with VB in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a website using asp.net and visual basic. When a user logs in they are directed from the login.aspx page to the user.aspx page and the session pulls up their username and a grid (the grid contains the logged in users medication from the database, with a command to select that selects the medicine Id):

DoctorId from the doctor table is stored as a foreign key in the Patient table

Pharmacy from is selected from the dropdown box +sql conneaction string:

MedicineId comes from the grid

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPharm" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SurgeryConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Pharmname FROM Pharmacy "></asp:SqlDataSource>


  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropPharm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPharm" DataTextField="Pharmname" DataValueField="Pharmname"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Once the option for medicine has been selected in the grid
Drop down list pharmacy has been selected 
AND button is clicked I want the Order_pres to update the following table:

[image]

Here is the code I am currently working on, there is no errors surfacing and when I test this nothing updates, hopefully someone elses knowledge can guide me on what I need to do to get the table to upddate - the labels included have been used to test pulling the values and have displayed on the labels when run:

```
  Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    lbldrop.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
    If e.CommandName = "UpdateMedicine" Then
        Session("MedicineID") = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())

    End If
End Sub





Protected Sub btnconfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnconfirm.Click

    ' Dropdown for pharmacy  someVariable = DropPharm.SelectedItem.Value  

    Dim PatientId As Integer = Session("PatientId")
    Dim PharmacyId As Integer = Session("PharmacyId")
    Dim MedicineId As Integer = Session("MedicineID")
    Dim DateOrdered As Date


    ' Get DoctorId from the patient table

    Dim DoctorId As Integer = "SELECT DoctorId FROM Patient  "

    '.Value = CInt(Session("DoctorId").ToString()) 



        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, PharmacyId, "
        query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
        query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"



        Dim sqlCs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SurgeryConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(sqlCs),
              comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            With comm.Parameters

            .Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PatientId")
            .Add("@DoctorId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("DoctorId")
            .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("MedicineID")
            .Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PharmacyId")
            .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(DateOrdered)



            End With


    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim rowInserted = comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If rowInserted = 1 Then
            lblconfirm.Text = "Order Placed"
        Else
            lblnoconfirm.Text = "Order not placed"
        End If
    Catch ex As SqlException
        lblnoconfirm.Text = "Unexpectd error: " & ex.Message
    End Try

    End Using





End Sub
```

Grid holding medicineId:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  >
  <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="UpdateMedicine" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MedicineId") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Purpose" HeaderText="Purpose" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Instrcutions" HeaderText="Instructions" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Sessions stored at login:

```
 Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
            Session("Username") = CStr(reader.Item("Username"))
            Session("DoctorId") = CStr(reader.Item("DoctorId"))
            found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
        End While
```

Steps that happen during update:

[image]

Comment: 4 parameters incoming, then you give 5. In the insert. idk

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement is missing the `MedicineId` in the column list:

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty
query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, PharmacyId, "
query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"
```

should be

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty
query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, MedicineId, PharmacyId, "
query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"
```

Comment: Hi Zohar - there are a few more problems with this - how to get the doctor Id from the patient table, the pharmacyid from the drop down and store the date when inserted. I will update the question to show this

Comment: I have updated the question, do you need any more information regarding what I am trying to do

Comment: I think where the problem lies is ** to get the pharmacyId**  (but dropdown has to show the pharmacy name  - `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPharm" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SurgeryConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Pharmname FROM Pharmacy "></asp:SqlDataSource>`

Comment: Actually, this is too much information and too many questions for a single post. Posts in SO should be for specific problems, your question is now so long it's hard to understand the problems you encounter. Please try to be more focused, and perhaps ask more questions regarding the other problems you encounter.

Comment: also to get the doctorId from the patient table `  Dim DoctorId As Integer = "SELECT DoctorId FROM Patient  " `

Comment: then store the date on the insert  - could you show me these 3 things and I can add the bounty?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find it really hard to answer such questions. It's way too much information for me.

Comment: I have broken the question down into a smaller part (a specific problem in my code) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072074/how-to-store-a-value-from-a-database-as-a-variable-with-vb-net possibly code you have a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

As Zohar pointed out, you're missing `MedicineId` field in your `INSERT INTO`  clause. That's one. Second, you misunderstanding the concept behind the session variables. Pay attention to this snippet:

```
Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While reader.Read()
    Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
    Session("Username") = CStr(reader.Item("Username"))
    Session("DoctorId") = CStr(reader.Item("DoctorId"))
    found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
End While
```

In the first iteration in the `While` loop you effectively create three variables in the session. But on subsequent iterations these variables get updated; no new variables for each record are created. Thus only the last record supplied by the reader is stored.

Later when you hit your logic from whatever row in the grid, it executes the T-SQL statement, supplying the last three `PatientId`, `Username` and `DoctorId` from the last record loaded at login. That's way you don't see the updates - they occur on a record you don't expect to be updated.

Now I don't see why you mess with the `Session` to do this. Instead loop through the cells in the `GridView` and feed the command parameters from there; don't mess with the `Session` at all.
Here is [good tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-Update-Edit-Delete-record-in-GridView-using-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx) on how to use `GridView`.