# How to store a value from a database as a variable with VB.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to store DoctorId from the patient table as a variable that I can then add to an insert statement (to be inserted into the Order_pres table). I am also trying to do this with PharmacyId from the pharmacy table.

The pharmacy name displays on the dropdown, however I dont know how to store the PharmacyId, as shown below:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPharm" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SurgeryConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Pharmname FROM Pharmacy "></asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:DropDownList ID="DropPharm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPharm" DataTextField="Pharmname" DataValueField="Pharmname"></asp:DropDownList>
```

How I am storing my variables and adding Ids to the insert query

```
 Protected Sub btnconfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnconfirm.Click

    ' Dropdown for pharmacy  someVariable = DropPharm.SelectedItem.Value  

    Dim PatientId As Integer = Session("PatientId")
    Dim PharmacyId As Integer = Session("PharmacyId")
    Dim MedicineId As Integer = Session("MedicineID")
    Dim DateOrdered As Date


    ' Get DoctorId from the patient table

    Dim DoctorId As Integer = "SELECT DoctorId FROM Patient  "

    '.Value = CInt(Session("DoctorId").ToString()) 



        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, PharmacyId, "
        query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
        query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"



        Dim sqlCs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SurgeryConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(sqlCs),
              comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            With comm.Parameters

            .Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PatientId")
            .Add("@DoctorId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("DoctorId")
            .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("MedicineID")
            .Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PharmacyId")
            .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(DateOrdered)



            End With
```

I have stored some of the sessions in the login.aspx page i.e when the user logs in:

```
  Public Function CheckUser(username As String, password As String) As Integer
    Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT * FROM Patient  Where Username=@USERNAME AND Password=@PASSWORD"
    Dim found = 0
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")

        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = username
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = password
        conn.Open()



        Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
            Session("Username") = CStr(reader.Item("Username"))
            Session("DoctorId") = CStr(reader.Item("DoctorId"))
            found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
        End While

        reader.Close()
    End Using
    Return (found)
End Function

enter code here
```

If I have been vague or any more information is needed a for the question is needed please let me know.

Kind regards :)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, seems like you are getting the `PharmacyId` from the `Session`. How is the dropdown related here and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Ignoring the asp aspects, your doctor query needs to be similar to your patient query in `CheckUser` routine so you'd have something like `"SELECT DoctorId FROM Patient WHERE PatientID=@PatID"` and you'd pass in that session variable. Then after the `ExecuteReader` call, `Session("DoctorId") = CInt(reader.Item("DoctorId"))`