# Relative path to local SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, relative-path

My school project is in VisualStudio, there I have a local SQL Database. I will submit the project to teacher, but I connect SQL with this way:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\michalbrany\source\repos\CZU_projekt\zakaznickeudaje.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Problem is, that my teacher will have downloaded the project to their Desktop, so this way will be incorrect.  Can I use this?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=..\..\..\..\..\..\zakaznickeudaje.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Or something else?

Comment: try it and you will know if you can do that or not. i would just use root folder instead of that 6 levels parent relative path

Comment: Taka a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409378) about using the `|DataDirectory|` substitution string in your connection string.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a connection string pointing to the actual ip address or hostname of the server with the corresponding username and password? See [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) where variation of connectionstrings can be found.

Hope this helps.