# How to bind local db records to datagridview in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview

I have a C# windows application with a local DB (SQL server express). I added the SQL server express to the application directory, everything is working fine, I can save to the database, but I found out that there is a copy of the database in the BIN folder, and that is where my saved records are. I am trying to bind a dataGridView to view saved records, the code runs without error, but the grid is not loaded with data as the dataSet table is null.

```
private void BindDataGridView()
{
  try
  {
     var select = "SELECT DISTINCT [Country],[State],[City] FROM dbo.StaffRecord ORDER BY [Country]     ASC,[State] DESC";
    var c = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

    var ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
}
```

My Connection String:

```
<add name="connection" connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial catalog=StaffRecord; Integrated Security=true;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Please, I want to be able to bind the DataGridView to the version of the local DB in the BIN folder since the Records are saved there or the one in the root directory of the application. Thanks

Comment: Are you using different connection strings for saving and reading data? With same connection string, you should be able to read saved data.

Comment: If you want to connect to specific database file set path to the file in attach db file name section of connection string `...;AttachDBFilename=C:\Myproject\bin\Database1.mdf;...`

Comment: using same connection string

Comment: How you know that data saved successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Entity Framework to map your db tables as classes. Than you can bind this class data to your DataGridView.

[Entity Framework tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

**EDIT:**
Check if you have `DataDirectory` set right in your connection string.
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented)

Comment: There is a requirement to use Ado.Net

Comment: EF uses ADO.NET in background.