# Can't connect to localdb when using [DataDirectory] in Windows Forms C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, sqlclient, datadirectory

I installed VS2019 and started training, I'm trying to connect to my DB using [DataDirectory] the DB File is in my Debug folder I'm using the following Conn string `cstr = @"server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=[DataDirectory]\test.mdf;Integrated Security = True;";`  but I'm getting this error

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file [DataDirectory]\test.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

but it will work if I change [datadirectory] with another fixed location like D:\Test.mdf

My Code:

```
string cstr;
SqlConnection cnn;
cstr = @"server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=[DataDirectory]\Test.mdf;Integrated Security = True;";
cnn = new SqlConnection(cstr);
cnn.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
cnn.Close();
```

Please help.

Comment: There is a difference between the description and the code (`D:\Test.mdf` vs. `\f.mdf`)

Comment: I guess you are using it wrong, it's |DataDirectory| instead of [DataDirectory]. a substitution string for your data directory.

Comment: @BelahceneBenzaraTahar i was using |DataDirectory| Like i used to do in .NetFramework years ago but now i start getting this err : Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' then someone gave me a solution and told me to write it like this [DataDirectory] it fixed the error but im havin this new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found my solution , i was using `System.Data.SqlClient` which doesn't support **|DataDirectory|** in: `AttachDbFilename=` . the new **SqlClient Provider** package : `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is what should be used from now on which supports **AppDomains** and `|DataDirectory|` macro in `AttachDbFilename=`

for using the **System.Data.SqlClient** the DB location in the connection string should be retrieved using : `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
so the connection string for `System.Data.SqlClient` Should be like this :

```
cstr = @"server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Database.mdf ; Integrated Security = True";
```

this should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

The substitution string is read from the current AppDomain.

[ADO.NET  |DataDirectory| where is this documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented)

But in .Net Core the AppDomain is a discontinued technology

[MS .Net blog | Porting to .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/porting-to-net-core/)

> ## App Domains
>
> **Why was it discontinued?** AppDomains require runtime support and are
> generally quite expensive. While still implemented by CoreCLR, it’s
> not available in .NET Native and we don’t plan on adding this
> capability there.

And I tested it and that string substitution did not work with .Net Core 3.1

So you have to implement that substituion by yourself or read the data from an external config file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is really about things not working how they used to. I have seen all sorts of answers regarding how to setup a connection with SQL Server LocalDB.

Here is my solution to get things back in VS 2022, .NET 6 and EF Core 6.

Use a connection string with both `Initial Catalog` and `AttachDbFilename`. Also, include a macro named `[DataDirectory]` to expand later on:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;AttachDbFilename=[DataDirectory]\\MyDatabase.mdf;"
```

Use the following code to obtain the actual connection string:

```
string connStr = config.GetConnectionStringWithExpand("MyDatabaseConnection")

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetConnectionStringWithExpand(this IConfiguration config, string name)
    {
        string projectDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string dataDirectory = Path.Combine(projectDirectory, "App_Data");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dataDirectory);

        string connStr = config.GetConnectionString(name);
        return connStr.Replace("[DataDirectory]", dataDirectory);
    }
}
```

When running the application from VisualStudio, the `App_Data` folder will be placed in the project folder, otherwise next to the entry point.